# Create subplots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I need to work with the hflights package and make subplots of every single weekday to show the delay of the airplanes (cancelled flights excluded). The problem is I'm not able to reproduce both x- and y-axis (x: month & y: delay in in min). I tried to use facet_wrap and facet_grid, but I'm not familiar to those function, because of not using ggplot2 that often.

Comment: You can use `facet_wrap(~DayOfWeek)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot will be clearer if you name the months and weekdays, arrange them in the correct order, and use a logarithmic scale on the y axis. You can use `facet_grid` to create subplots for each weekday.

```r
library(hflights)
library(tidyverse)

weekday <- c('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 
             'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')

hflights %>% 
  mutate(WeekDay = factor(weekday[DayOfWeek], weekday),
         Month = factor(month.abb[Month], month.abb)) %>%
  filter(Cancelled == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, DepDelay)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(.~WeekDay) +
  labs(x = 'Month', y = 'Departure delay (log scale)')
```

[image]

To get a single line going through each panel, you need to have an average for each unique combination of month and day. The simplest way to get this is via `geom_smooth`

```r
hflights %>% 
  mutate(WeekDay = factor(weekday[DayOfWeek], weekday),
         Month = factor(month.abb[Month], month.abb)) %>%
  filter(Cancelled == 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, DepDelay, group = WeekDay)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(.~WeekDay) +
  labs(x = 'Month', y = 'Departure delay (log scale)')
```

[image]

Though you can also summarize the data yourself and use `geom_line`

```r
hflights %>% 
  filter(Cancelled == 0) %>%
  mutate(WeekDay = factor(weekday[DayOfWeek], weekday),
         Month = factor(month.abb[Month], month.abb)) %>%
  group_by(Month, WeekDay) %>%
  summarize(Delay = mean(DepDelay)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Delay, group = WeekDay)) +
  geom_line(color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(.~WeekDay) +
  labs(x = 'Month', y = 'Departure delay (log scale)')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you really helped me out. But what would be necessary to change to make it from geom_boxplot to geom_line?

Comment: @ManjiroSano see my update for two options

Comment: Is there any certain reason why the second code with geom_line doesn't work when changing DepDelay to ArrDelay or to DepDelay + ArrDelay?

Comment: @ManjiroSano it's because `ArrDelay` has NA values. Try changing `mean(DepDelay)` to `mean(ArrDelay, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

now since you didn't post the code let's assume you have saved a plot that plots everything in one plot under a.

```
a + facet_grid(rows = vars(weekday))
```

("weekday" is the column name where the weekdays are in, replace it if they are named diffrently)

If this isn't what you were searching for, it would be great if you could post some code...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to show the `ArrDelay`,

```
hflights %>% 
  filter(Cancelled!=1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Month), y=mean(ArrDelay,na.rm=T)))+
  geom_col()+
  labs(x='Month',y='Mean arrival Delay')+
  facet_wrap(~DayOfWeek)
```